# Better way to implement Duplicate checker?

Tags: c++, arrays, oop, exception

I have created an exception handling case where it should detect if there is a duplicate in an Array set, but the try and catch is inside a for loop iterating through the set and was wondering if there was another efficient way in creating this duplicate checker.

Here is the function that throw's the exception:

```
namespace cs_set {

    template<class ItemType>
    void ArraySet<ItemType>::add(const ItemType& newEntry) {
        //auto result1 = std::find(std::begin(items), std::end(items), newEntry);
        //int locatedIndex = getIndexOf(new);
        if (std::find(std::begin(items), std::end(items), newEntry) != std::end(items))
       {
            throw DuplicateItemError();
       }  
        else 
       {  
            items[itemCount] = newEntry;
            itemCount++;
       }  
    }
```

Here is the for loop that implements it and was wondering if I could make it better or more efficient:

```
void setTester(ArraySet<string>& set)
{
    cout << "isEmpty: returns " << set.isEmpty()
         << "; should be 1 (true)" << endl;
    displaySet(set);

    std::string items[] = {"one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "one"};
    cout << "Add 6 items to the set: " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    
        try {
            set.add(items[i]);
            cout << items[i] << endl;
        }
        catch (ArraySet<string>::DuplicateItemError e)
        {
            //set.add(items[i]);
            cout << "IT IS A DUPLICATE!" << endl;
        }
    }

    displaySet(set);

    cout << "isEmpty: returns " << set.isEmpty()
         << "; should be 0 (false)" << endl;
}
```

Comment: There's no more efficient way to find an item in an array other than to loop through each item in the array. The way to improve efficiency is to change the data structure, a hash set or a balanced tree are the two standard choices. C++ offers both of these as part of it's standard library (std::unordered_set and std::set respectively).

Comment: Having said that using exceptions for non-exceptional situtations is not recommended. Maybe `add` should just return a boolean value to say whether the item has been added or not.

Comment: That doesn't seem like a good case for exceptions. A less clunky interface would either not insert anything or replace the old value. Add a way to check whether an element already is in the set and you can let the user decide whether it is an exceptional error or not.

Comment: This has nothing to do with OOP.